# How can I weight each point in one-class SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, support-vector-machine, binary-classification, anomaly-detection

I want to give weights to some data points

Specifically, these are points related to anomalies

(I'm implementing one-class SVM for *anomaly detection*)

Exactly, I want to consider some data points that are likely to be anomalies as more important data points

Is it possible in one-class SVM ?

Comment: Hello, please keep all the necessary details in the question as it seems difficult to understand without related context.

Comment: @hanugm Hi, one-class SVM is known as a good anomaly detector (imbalanced binary classifier) However, I want to give weights to some data point in advance, so that the points can be anomalies in one-class SVM classifier

Comment: [This might help](https://github.com/yzhao062/pyod/blob/master/pyod/models/ocsvm.py)

Comment: @Yahya Thk you!